# How to split django views request into several ones

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have Django app which makes lots of different analysis

Here is the structure of the view:

```
def analysis(request):
   making analysis 1 
    ...
   making analysis 2 
    ...
   making analysis 3 
    ...

    ........

   making analysis 50 
    ...
return render(request, 'checkapp/shots.html', var)
```

The problem is that all these analysis takes about 1-2 minutes. While development I tested my app locally and it is working fine there. But when I deployed it on Heroku, it turned out, that heroku has 30 sec timeout limit.

How can I split this process into several smaller ones, so I could get responses each 10 sec, for example?

Or maybe there is some other solution for my problem?

Comment: Depending on the set up of your django project, the most straightforward strategy is to split your methods into different views, and use AJAX to call the views asynchronously after the initial page has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use background jobs to deals with your analyses, instead of placing your analysis logic into the view.

You can use [celery tas](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html)k to each analysis when needed.

For example:

```
@app.task()
def making_analysis_1(*args):
    ...
```